# SAS ODS PDF: Table of Contents

Tags: pdf, sas, tableofcontents

Here a SAS code sample:

```
ODS LISTING CLOSE;
GOPTIONS DEV=SASPRTC;
ODS PDF FILE="test_toc.pdf" CONTENTS=YES ;
ODS DOCUMENT NAME=REPORTTOC(WRITE);

ODS PROCLABEL="1 - Title level 1" ;
TITLE1 "1 - Title level 1" ;
TITLE2 "1.1 - Title level 2: Horsepower" ;
PROC REPORT DATA=SASHELP.CARS(obs=5) NOWINDOWS CONTENTS="1.1 - Title level 2: Horsepower"; 
    COLUMN Horsepower ;
    DEFINE Horsepower / DISPLAY PAGE CONTENTS="" ;*Note1: According to SAS documentation, contents="" should delete "Table 1" from the TOC but it does not work;
RUN;
TITLE2 "1.2 - Title level 2: Type" ;
PROC REPORT DATA=SASHELP.CARS(obs=5) NOWINDOWS CONTENTS="1.2 - Title level 2: Type"; 
    COLUMN type ;
    DEFINE type / DISPLAY PAGE CONTENTS="" ;*Note2: idem;
RUN;

ODS PROCLABEL="2 - Title level 1" ;
TITLE1 "2 - Title level 1" ;
TITLE2 "2.1 - Title level 2: Horsepower" ;
TITLE3 "2.1.1 - Title level 3: Horsepower" ;
PROC REPORT DATA=SASHELP.CARS(obs=5) NOWINDOWS CONTENTS="2.1 - Title level 2: Horsepower"; 
    COLUMN Horsepower ;
    DEFINE Horsepower / DISPLAY PAGE CONTENTS="2.1.1 - Title level 3: Horsepower" ;
RUN;
TITLE2 "2.2 - Title level 2: Type" ;
TITLE3 "2.2.1 - Title level 3: Type" ;
*Note3: Can I add another level of title (TITLE4) in the TOC before the display of this PROC REPORT? ;
PROC REPORT DATA=SASHELP.CARS(obs=5) NOWINDOWS CONTENTS="2.2 - Title level 2: Type"; 
    COLUMN type ;
    DEFINE type / DISPLAY PAGE CONTENTS="2.2.1 - Title level 3: Type" ;
RUN;

ODS DOCUMENT CLOSE;
ODS PDF CLOSE;
GOPTIONS RESET=ALL;
ODS LISTING;

PROC DOCUMENT NAME=REPORTTOC(update);

MOVE Report#2\Report#1 TO report#1 ;

MOVE Report#4\Report#1 TO report#3;
RUN;

ODS PDF FILE='test_toc.pdf' CONTENTS=YES ;
REPLAY; RUN;
ODS PDF CLOSE;
QUIT;
```

[This code produces this TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLnFF.png)

My problem is that I would like to be able to add levels in the TOC without using more procedures (Cf. Note3 in the code sample).

I would like to link directly the TITLE statement in the TOC without using ODS PROCLABEL="text" or CONTENTS="text".

Is it possible (I'm running SAS 9.2)?

Comment: While the community of stack overflow loves to help people solve problems, they do expect people asking questions to show that they've tried to solve the problem themselves first.  There are plenty of table of contents examples on google.  If you have done this and are having a specific problem about creating the table of contents, please include the relevant code that shows the problem you are having.

Comment: What is 'automatic dialling'? Is that links/bookmarks?

Comment: @RobertPenridge I really tried to solve my problem first, and I saw lots of things on table of contents but only with 2 or 3 levels. The "best" TOC that I made is using "ODS PROCLABEL='My Label'" and with a PROC DOCUMENT to re-organize my report. But if I want to have more than 2 or  3 levels, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Reeza: 'automatic dialing' means that I would like to have automatic numbers before the title:
1
 1.1
 1.2
etc.

Comment: @A.Beauvais You get better answers if you do a few things.  First, write up an example code using SASHELP datasets or data you provide in datalines, that produces what you have so far.  Then explain how that's not sufficient.

Comment: @Joe I edited my question; I hope that it will show you that I did things before asking my question and I hope that my question is more clear and useful.

Comment: This question is much better now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the part of the issue.  It looks like it is the `PROCLABEL` option and the `CONTENTS` keywords that are being used to build the TOC, not the `TITLE` keywords.  The `TITLE` keywords simply detail what the heading on each page should be.  I've taken your example and simplified it a little to illustrate this point:

```
ODS LISTING CLOSE;
ODS PDF FILE="test_toc.pdf" CONTENTS=YES ;
ODS DOCUMENT NAME=REPORTTOC(WRITE);

GOPTIONS DEV=SASPRTC;

ODS PROCLABEL="Proc Label 1" ;
TITLE1 "1 - Title level 1 ";
TITLE2 "1.1 - Title level 2 " ;
TITLE3 "1.1.1 - Title level 3 " ;
TITLE4 "1.1.1.1 - Title level 4 " ;
PROC REPORT DATA=SASHELP.CARS(obs=5) NOWINDOWS CONTENTS="Contents 1"; 
    COLUMN Horsepower ;
    DEFINE Horsepower / DISPLAY PAGE CONTENTS="Contents 2" ;
RUN;

ODS DOCUMENT CLOSE;
ODS PDF CLOSE;
ODS LISTING;
```

Looking through the documentation I'm not sure how this could be nested further but perhaps this will help you find the solution, or help someone else figure out the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is my issue, not be abble to use the 'TITLE' keywords to build the TOC.

Comment: @A.Beauvais Looking into it a little more it seems like `proc document` may be required to achieve this.  I don't have time right now but will try to revisit later.

Comment: I started to read some documentations on `proc document`. I'll let you know if I find something interesting to solve the issue.